# Add Space Between Panels of Openair windRose Plots

Tags: r, openair

I created some windrose plots using the `openair` package and I'm pretty happy with how they turned out but aesthetically it would be nice to have some space between panels. Here's an example:

```
# windrose plot----
library(openair)
data("mydata")

windRose(mydata[1:144,], ws="ws", wd="wd", 
         paddle = F, 
         type = 'weekday', 
         key.header = 'Wind Speed (m/s)',
         key.footer = "",
         annotate = F,
         angle = 30, # angle of "spokes"...sort of bins for wind direction
         cols =  'jet',
         key.position = 'right',
         dig.lab = 2,
         statistic = 'prop.count', #“prop.count” sizes bins according to the 
         # proportion of the frequency of measurements
         fontsize = 20,
         grid.line = 100,
         max.freq = 105, # maximum value for the radial limits
         key = list(header = "Wind Speed (m/s)",
                    footer = '',
                    labels = c('0 to 2', '2 to 4', 
                               '4 to 6','6 or more'),
                    breaks = c(0,2,4,6)),
         layout = c(6,1)
)
```

Anyone have any ideas of how to add space between the panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found that this plot function utilizes trellis plots, here is a good rundown on them: [https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/787/lectures-trellis.pdf](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eihaka/787/lectures-trellis.pdf)

Specifically the `xyplot` function is used to create the trellis plot. The help documentation for `?xyplot` shows that you can adjust the argument `between` to achieve spacing between panels. The `between` argument is a list containing x and y values that represent space between panels. Therefore we can adjust the above code simply by adding the argument `between = list(x=0.25, y = 0.25)` and can adjust x and y to our preference like this:

```
library(openair)
data("mydata")

windRose(mydata[1:144,], ws="ws", wd="wd", 
         paddle = F, 
         type = 'weekday', 
         key.header = 'Wind Speed (m/s)',
         key.footer = "",
         annotate = F,
         angle = 30, # angle of "spokes"...sort of bins for wind direction
         cols =  'jet',
         key.position = 'right',
         dig.lab = 2,
         statistic = 'prop.count', #“prop.count” sizes bins according to the 
         # proportion of the frequency of measurements
         fontsize = 20,
         grid.line = 100,
         max.freq = 105, # maximum value for the radial limits
         key = list(header = "Wind Speed (m/s)",
                    footer = '',
                    labels = c('0 to 2', '2 to 4', 
                               '4 to 6','6 or more'),
                    breaks = c(0,2,4,6)),
         layout = c(6,1),
         between = list(x=0.25, y=0.25)
)
```